# Determining introduction date/Swift version of Swift components

Tags: ios, swift2, uistackview

Here is the date in the revision history for the UIStackView: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015256-CH99-SW1

Since it doesn't have a history and the first entry is dated 9/16/2015, does that mean it was introduced with Swift 2?

Comment: Do not confuse framework with language.

Comment: UIStackVIew is under with new concept in xcode 7/ iOS 9 feature also , it is not based an language

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Xcode7/iOS9 can only be used with Swift2 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates are irrelevant. Go to the top of this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015256-CH1-SW29

Read the Availability entry. That is all you need to know.

Comment: But iOS9 can only be used with Swift 2 (Xcode7) right?